# SQL Inner Join returning Union

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am new to SQL Joins and a problem required me to use the Inner Join. So far I know that the inner join joins two tables and gives the common data.
In my case, I am getting the union of the two tables. 
For Example: 
     Let's say I have two tables 'A' and 'B'.
     Table 'A' have 180 values(Rows)
     Table 'b' have 3 values(Rows)
On using the inner join I got 540 values(Rows).

For Example: 
     Let's say I have two tables 'A' and 'B'.
     Table 'A' have 180 values(Rows)
     Table 'b' have 3 values(Rows)
On using the inner join I got 540 values(Rows).

```
Code Example: 
select a.TableAData, b.TableBData 
from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.id = b.id
where a.id = 'some value'
```

Expected rows are at max should be 180. but the actual rows are 540.

Comment: The "union all" would return 183 rows (180 + 3). Your join is returning 180 x 3 because each row in table A is matching by id on *all* 3 rows on table B. Make sure that the condition of the `ON` in the join is actually relating both tables (and not `A.id = A.id`).

Comment: It seems like all values of Id column in both TableAData and TableBData are the same. Key to successful join is correct 'on' condition.

Comment: @EzLo Yes, I also agree with this. The problem must be in "on" condition.

Comment: you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..  the join work as you have obtained  ( is the cartesian produce between the matching row form both table  180x3)